# Can I use thunderclient npm package to run the api requests from a json

Tags: graphql, thunderclient

Is it possible or is there a way to use thunderclient npm package to run the list of graphql requests from a json file in a CLI not from VSCode? Something like this "npx thunder-client run api_tests.json"

I tried to run this "npx thunder-client run api_tests.json" command as part of github workflow to test the collection of graphql requests. But this is not working and I got an error "could not determine executable to run".

Answer (score 1):

Running from exported collection json file is not supported

You can use `npx tc --col 'collectionName'`

See documentation
https://rangav.medium.com/thunder-client-cli-a-new-way-to-test-apis-inside-vscode-d91eb5c71d8e

If you have further questions please reach out on our GitHub page

Comment: Thanks for your response. I still have some questions and will reach out to you on GitHub.